# Creating an assembly code without any proc declaration

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I am trying to define a simple empty file in assembly. But this throws errors

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _mainCRTStartup  Project1    D:\assembly\Project1\Project1\LINK  1
```

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK1120 1 unresolved externals  Project1    D:\assembly\Project1\Debug\Project1.exe 1
```

```
include irvine32.inc


.data


.code



end
```

Comment: you are trying to link it if you want an object then dont link it

Comment: if you want to link it then you need to provide the minimum global labels required for a successful link, and/or use your own bootstrap and not the stock one.  (which implies your own linker script)

Answer (score 1):

You should at least specify an entry point for your program, I don't know which ide are you using, but it should be in advanced linker properties/settings or something like this. Basically the linker doesn't know what to do with this. I would also add at least the entry point in the code if you are trying to get it to compile, or the linker won't know what to make of it.

Comment: I am using microsoft visual studio. what could be the minimal entry point like ? Also do you suggest any other editor from MSVS ?

Comment: Try to add a main entrypoint and a ret instruction, that should work. I don't know if 0 instructions would make the linker go crazy. MSVS is fine, although i prefer vim

Comment: @DanielGomez: Having 0 instructions wouldn't be a problem for the linker, only at run-time when execution fell through from the entry point label into whatever got linked next.  But yeah, I'd definitely suggest `foo: ret` at the entry point.